# Reference- what is wrong with my codeigniter code

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

hello everyone i write a codeigniter function to return data fro database 
this is my function

```
  public function get_total_results($filtering = false)
{
    if ($filtering) {
        $this->get_filtering();
    }

    foreach ($this->joins as $val) {
        $this->ci->db->join($val[0], $val[1], $val[2]);
    }

    foreach ($this->where as $val) {
        $this->ci->db->where($val[0], $val[1], $val[2]);
    }

    foreach ($this->or_where as $val) {
        $this->ci->db->or_where($val[0], $val[1], $val[2]);
    }

    foreach ($this->group_by as $val) {
        $this->ci->db->group_by($val);
    }

    foreach ($this->like as $val) {
        $this->ci->db->like($val[0], $val[1], $val[2]);
    }

    if (strlen($this->distinct) > 0) {
        $this->ci->db->distinct($this->distinct);
        $this->ci->db->select($this->columns);
    }

    $query = $this->ci->db->get($this->table, null, null, false);

    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

but i get an error of

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>    Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function num_rows() on boolean

in  line of `return $query->num_rows();`
i don't know what is wrong with my code that i got this error so i know the error in last line in returning result any suggestion or idea

Comment: Please see creating a [mcve].

Comment: `num_rows()` on boolean has been addressed many a time here before. essentially it means your query failed e.g. returned false so any more operations on the object is impossible `num_rows()` `result()` `row()` .etc. Turn on `db_debug` in database.php to figure out your error message. Also please refrain from "why isn't my code working" questions. It is literally the name of a close option.

Comment: first, I need to ask why there is `$this->ci->db->join()` instead of `$this->db->join()` ? secondly if you are using `method chaining` with `join()` then where is `from()`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the line

```
$query = $this->ci->db->get($this->table, null, null, false);
// Note: all you really need is $this->ci->db->get($this->table);
```

It is assigning the value `false` to `$query`. That usually happens when Query Builder creates a SQL statement that does not make sense - it happens.

You can see what Query Builder creates this way

```
// comment out the get() call
// $this->ci->db->get($this->table);
// run this instead
$sql = $this->db->get_compiled_select($this->table);
echo $sql;
// remove the comments once you see where the problem is
//return $query->num_rows();
```

You will probably be able to see where the SQL statement syntax is wrong and adjust your earlier code accordingly.

You might want to add a check of the `get()` return to your logic, e.g.

```
$query = $this->ci->db->get($this->table);
// Is $query truthy? (not false, null, etc)
if(! empty($query))
{
    return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

get() method of codeigniter have syntax like:

> **get([$table = ''[, $limit = NULL[, $offset = NULL]]])**
>
> Parameters:    $table (string) – The table to query $limit (int) – The
>   LIMIT clause $offset (int) – The OFFSET clause
>
> Returns:   CI_DB_result instance (method chaining)
>
> Return type:   CI_DB_result

You have passed more than three parameters. So, Please check the parameters. It may resolve your problem.

Refer [this](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#CI_DB_query_builder::get) for more information.

Comment: it really doesn't have any effect - php doesn't care if you hand over more params than necessary to a function ...